# Logitech T650 multitouch gestures

Tags: mouse, multi-touch, trackpad, gestures

I am currently running elementary Os Freya (based on ubuntu 14.04) and I was wondering the best way to enable multitouch gestures for my external Logitech Trackpad T650.

I tried to install Ginn and Touchegg from the package manager but neither of them is reacting when I draw a gesture.

The solution I have adopted is mapping keys generated by the trackpad to actions with xbindkeys. But the result is not really confortable. It's buggy and the gestures are really limited.

for instance (Mod4 + D is the key generated when I swipe down on the T650 with 3 fingers).

I have used this tuto to make this config.
[HERE](http://franklinstrube.com/blog/logitech-t650-wireless-touchpad-ubuntu/)

```
#Three-finger swipe down
"dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:6"
   Mod4 + D
```

Does anyone has succeeded to use gesture with the T650?
What would be the best solution?

I would like to have for example three fingers gestures to move windows, close windows change workspaces or specific gestures inside chrome to open/navigate tabs.

Comment: I know it seems ridiculous, but basic functionality like this is what keeps me from switching to linux at my daily driver. I've gone through your steps, and have upgraded the T650 firmware to `041.001.00038`. This firmware update is supposed to move multi-touch driving to the device itself, but the results were lack luster. If I could get this to work, I'd be using linux on my desktop and laptop as the sole OS.